# Ubuntu 22.04 ZFS root no boot entries being added to grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, zfs

I have a workstation that was originally installed as 20.04 with zsys and has since been upgraded to 22.04. I have been using it since April with no issues, but yesterday a piece of software locked up the machine and somehow messed up GRUB.  I have been able to boot the machine both with a live image and by using the GRUB command line, but for some reason whenever I run `update-grub`, the only thing that gets added to the GRUB menu is `"UEFI Firmware Settings"`.  I have not changed any grub or kernel settings or packages, nor any ZFS settings.

output from `update-grub`:

```
root@voyager:/home/jamie# !upd
update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@lfs-init
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@lfs-init
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@lfs-init
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@lfs-init
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@pre-jammy-upgrade
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@pre-jammy-upgrade
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.13.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@pre-jammy-upgrade
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@pre-jammy-upgrade
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@upgrade
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@upgrade
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@upgrade
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@upgrade
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_XXXXXX@autozsys_XXXXXX
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

I have tried all the normal system recovery things I can think of, but I am completely stumped as to why grub is no longer adding boot entries to `grub.cfg`... it is as if it is ignoring `bpool` altogether.

Can anyone provide any insight into this or what I should try?

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the 22.04.2LTS installer created the EFI boot partition on the correct disk, but then wrote the wrong partition in the `/etc/fstab` file.

The solution was quite simple:

1. mount the correct EFI partition somewhere (say `/mnt/efi/`)
2. create `grub.cfg` in the right place by running `grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/efi/grub/grub.cfg`
3. edit `/etc/fstab` and replace the EFI boot partition (that's the one usually mounted at `/boot/efi`)
4. reboot